# Actions must be plain objects error while testing react app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am having problems while testing,  and am not quite sure how to fix it:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
> actions.
>
> ```
>   13 | 
>   14 |   useEffect( () => {
> > 15 |     dispatch(getPostsAction())
>      |     ^
>   16 |   }, [])
> ```

I am using jest + enzyme, this is my test : Post.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Post from './Post';
import { storeFactory } from 'testUtils';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock("store/actions/PostsAction")
import {getPostsAction as mockGetPostsAction} from 'store/actions/PostsAction'

const setup = (initialState = {})=>{
    const store = storeFactory(initialState);
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Post /></Provider>)
    return wrapper; 
}

test('getPostsAction on Post mount', ()=>{
        const wrapper = setup()             
        expect(mockGetPostsAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) 
})
```

This is my Post component:

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react"
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {getPostsAction} from 'store/actions/PostsAction'

function Post() {

useEffect( () => {    
    dispatch(getPostsAction())
  }, [])
 
  const posts= useSelector(state => state.posts.posts)

}

.....

export default Post;
```

This is my action: PostsAction.js

```
export const getPostsAction =  ()=>{
    return async (dispatch) =>{

        try{
            const {data} = await $http.get('/api/posts')                        
            dispatch(setPosts(data.data))       
        }catch(e){
       
        }
    }
}

const setPosts = posts => ({
    type: SET_POSTS,
    payload: posts
})
```

**EDITED:**

testUtils.js

```
import checkPropTypes from 'check-prop-types';
import { middlewares } from 'store/store';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from 'store/reducers';

.....

 export const storeFactory = (initialState) => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
  }
```

store/store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './reducers'

export const middlewares = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {},
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares) 
);

export default store
```

How could I fix the error? thank you.

Comment: What's `storeFactory`, did you add redux-thunk middleware when creating the redux store?

Comment: thanks for responding, storeFactory comes from testUtils.js, I updated the question.